# node.js ws - how to detect a new websocket connection before handshake

Tags: node.js

I am using the ws addon from [einaros](https://github.com/einaros/ws/blob/master/doc/ws.md).

I want to detect the event that the new connection is established before handshake.

The reason is : the client may establish too many TCP connections without any handshake nor send data, I need a way to avoid this kind of attack.

Thanks

Comment: A connection is not established until the handshake is made, so you can't `detect the event that the new connection is established before handshake`. You can "detect a SYN packet" for example, but not with `node.js`. You should use your firewall or create your own program using `lib pcap` to spoof and handle certain packets.

Comment: Is there a way to hack into the ws addon to get the TCP connection establish event?